# MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express can't edit or create SQL tables remotely

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, netbeans-7, visual-web-developer-2010

I've got a SQL database registrated on HelioHost.org and when i try to access this Db via NetBeans, it's fine. I can edit tables, make new one etc.
However when I try to do the same in MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I can set connection to this Db, I can see already existing tables, but I can't create or edit them.

Is there any way how to get full access to remote SQL via MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of feature restriction. Please refer to this article below:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/creating-a-database-connection-to-a-remote-sql-server-database-within-visual-web-developer

> Although you may create and alter a SQL Server .mdf database within
>   your project, Visual Web Developer doesn't support opening a table
>   definition or adding a new table from your SQL Server 2000 database.
>   But it does allow "Show Table Data." It allows you to see the names of
>   your stored procedures, but not to edit or view their content, just
>   the properties. It is very limited, but you may wish to have it just
>   for those purposes.

You might want to use free SQL Server Management Studio Express to do that.